# How can i make mirror files as if updated a folder the other one gets updated with the same txt

Tags: files, 22.04, dropbox

i use password managing app and using dropbox to connect it to the cloud i have 2 copies of the file one inside the dropbox folder which is automatically uploaded to the cloud and the other is in my home directory the one in the home is the only one which gets updated when i do changes in the app so how can i connect the two files to be identical?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You should install `Dropbox` from `Ubuntu software`.

This works both ways. If you save a file to `/Home/Dropbox` it will then be automatically updated to `Dropbox` and if you save a file directly to `Dropbox` it will sync with your `/Home/Dropbox` directory.

[image]

I've been using Dropbox this way for some considerable time and have never experienced a problem with synchronisation between my system and `Dropbox` in the cloud.

Comment: yeah this works fine but my problem is that i have a file in the home directory that changes alot and i copied it to the dropbox folder to be uploaded to the cloud but the changes that happens to the file in the home directory doesn't apply to the file in the dropbox folder i want the two files to synchronize then the dropbox app will send edits for the file to the cloud